# Manage Screen Display and Bottom button when keyboard open and hide in iOS same as Android

Tags: android, ios, swift, keyboard-events, uikeyboard

**Expected Functionality** is the same as it happens in Android devices (Check below Images):

[image: When Keyboard is not open Android]

When Keyboard opens, the bottom button is animated to up and also the screen shifted a little upwards, depending on the Device Screen size. Check below Image

[image: When Keyboard is Open Android]

I am trying to implement the same functionality in my iOS Application.
Here is my code:

```
    @objc func keyboardWillChangeFrame(_ notification: Notification?) {
    guard let keyboardRect = (notification?.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {return}

    let screenY = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    let shrunkViewHeight = screenY - keyboardRect.height
    self.forwardButton.frame.origin.y = keyboardRect.origin.y
    if (shrunkViewHeight < screenY/1.5) {
        let screenShift = ((screenY/2) - shrunkViewHeight)
        if notification?.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification || notification?.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                self.view.frame.origin.y = screenShift

            }
        }else{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What is Happening presently:**
The button sometimes remains at the bottom especially when the first responder changes from one TextField to another without closing the keyboard.

Solution Expected: The mentioned functionality should work for all iPhones ranging from iPhone 6 to latest XR. Open to the third party suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

```
@IBOutlet weak var BottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! //your last item in bottom of your view controller constraint

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    self.registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
}


func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
}

func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardNotification(_ notification: Foundation.Notification) {

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {

        let endFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
        let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions().rawValue
        let animationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

        if (endFrame?.origin.y)! >= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
            self.sendCmntViewBottomConstraint?.constant = 0.0
        } else {
            self.sendCmntViewBottomConstraint?.constant = endFrame!.size.height
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: TimeInterval(0), options: animationCurve, animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

```
@IBOutlet weak var BottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! //your last item in bottom of your view controller constraint

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    self.registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
}


func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardNotification(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
}

func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

@objc func keyboardNotification(_ notification: Foundation.Notification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        let endFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
        let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIView.AnimationOptions().rawValue
        let animationCurve:UIView.AnimationOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)
        if (endFrame?.origin.y)! >= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
            self.requestBttnButtomMargin?.constant = 24.0
        } else {
            self.requestBttnButtomMargin?.constant = endFrame!.size.height + 10
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                       delay: TimeInterval(0),
                       options: animationCurve,
                       animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                       completion: nil)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It would be great if you can add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: @user832 you can check this example [https://github.com/AmirDaliri/KeyboardHandler]

Comment: your solution is limited to less number of textfields, please check the image in question, the textfield are at the top and thus if you manipulate the bottom constraint, there can be a case where textfield goes out of screen bounds.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:
1. Your code sample doesn’t show it, but it seems as though you are sending all notifications via this method. I recommend handling willView and willHide separately. You may not need to subscribe to didChangeFrame.

2. What is the shrunkViewHeight < screenY/1.5 check for? It will always return false on any sizeable device.
3. UIScreen usage here is dangerous, particularly for iPad or landscape supporting apps. Check against view.frame instead.
4. Are you using auto layout? In this case, look into handling the change by changing a constraint.

Here is a code sample for willShow that should help you on your way:

```
    var viewFrame = view.frame
    viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardRect.height
    if viewFrame.contains(forwardButton.frame) {
        return // Do nothing, button is visible
    }
    // Modify your button frame here
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestions will change accordingly, answer to your point 2: this check lets me know do screen needs to be shifted upwards because, in smaller devices the bottom button can overlap the textfield when the keyboard is open.
Also can you tell me any particular reason for "I recommend handling willView and willHide separately."

Comment: I see. I would use the CGRect function intersects() to check for an overlap. I recommend handling willShow and willHide separately, simply because functions that do only one thing are much easier to manage - you are less likely to introduce bugs.

Comment: i will try using intersects and update the question accordingly.